# Start Python scripts with launchctl (OSX)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, launchctl

I have a very simple test scrip that I want my computer to run every 60 seconds - `time_test_script.py`. The script simply saves a `.txt` file with current time as name and writes some text onto the file. The file is in `/Users/me/Documents/Python` dir.

```
import datetime
import os.path
path = '/Users/me/Desktop/test_dir'
name_of_file = '%s' %datetime.datetime.now()
completeName = os.path.join(path, name_of_file+".txt")
file1 = open(completeName, "w")
toFile = 'test'
file1.write(toFile)
file1.close()
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

I also have a `.plist` file – `test.plist` that is in `/Library/LaunchAgents` dir.

`test.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/me/Documents/Python/time_test_script.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I run the script manually it works fine, i.e. is creates a `.txt` file in the specified directory. However, when I try to initiate `launchctl` from the Terminal nothing happens.

```
 $ launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist 
 $ launchctl start com.test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First argument in ProgramArguments must be your python interpreter.

(used a pyenv interpreter as example)

Also add the workingdirectory to something because it defaults to `/` which is readonly.

```
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/timetest/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Users/me/Documents/Python/time_test_script.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/Users/me/Documents/Python</string>
```

for debugging `sudo launch list com.test` will help you:

(example from one of my own services)

if `ExitStatus!=0` and `PID` missing something may be wrong.

```
{
    "StandardOutPath" = "/var/log/gitlab.mobj.board.log";
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
    "StandardErrorPath" = "/var/log/gitlab.mobj.board.log";
    "Label" = "gitlab.mobj.board";
    "OnDemand" = false;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "PID" = 312;
    "Program" = "/Users/mobj/.pyenv/versions/gitlab-mobj-board/bin/python";
    "ProgramArguments" = (                
        "/Users/mobj/.pyenv/versions/gitlab-mobj-board/bin/python";
        "/dist/gitlab-mobj-board/main.py";        
    );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are running a script without using `python scriptname.py`, then the script needs to be marked executable (`chmod a+x scriptname.py` from the command line) and the first line should tell the system which interpreter to use, which in this case will be `#!/usr/bin/python`.

For example:

```
Sapphist:~ zoe$ cat >test.py
print "Hello World"
Sapphist:~ zoe$ ./test.py
-bash: ./test.py: Permission denied
```

With just the execute bit set:

```
Sapphist:~ zoe$ cat >test.py
print "Hello World"

Sapphist:~ zoe$ chmod a+x test.py
Sapphist:~ zoe$ ./test.py
./test.py: line 1: print: command not found
```

With both an interpreter and execute bit:

```
Sapphist:~ zoe$ cat >test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Hello World!"

Sapphist:~ zoe$ chmod a+x test.py
Sapphist:~ zoe$ ./test.py
Hello World!
Sapphist:~ zoe$
```